# Javascript - Getting the last word in a line

Tags: javascript, word-wrap

Here is an example:

```
<div><span style="font-size:15px;">some text here which is </span>
<span style="color:red;">split automatically by the browser.</span></div>
```

which the browser renders as (with styles of course):

```
some text here which is split
automatically by the browser.
```

I am building up a javascript application which has to understand the last word in each line (`split` in this case). Currently I am using the CSS `white-space` property to deal with overflow text. Therefore, the browser will not give me a clue about where it does break the line. So, what would be a nice function to understand the last word in each line?

**EDIT**

I am using pure-javascript, so jQuery would not be an option and the `white-space` property is applied to the `div`. So actually, think the `div` as a line renderer.

Comment: are the lines always wrapped by span? is jQuery an option or just plain JS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673752/searching-for-a-last-word-in-javascript

Comment: @msanford, I've already checked that question but it does not answer what I ask. It will actually return the last word in each element, not the last word in the line.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I think the missing jQuery tag is enough to answer your second question

Comment: @ajax333221 just making sure. often times someone answers a truly JS approach and gets outsmarted by another answer that uses jQuery because the OP was amazed that it just worked in a shorter amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the whole sentence word-by-word keeping track of the height changes. Here is some explanation via code:

HTML:

```
<div id="flop" class="foobar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
<br>
<button value="Go" onclick="foo();">Go</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Script:

```
function foo(){
    var d = document.getElementById('flop');
    var t = d.innerHTML;
    var w = t.split(' ');       

    d.innerHTML = w[0];
    var height = d.clientHeight;
    for(var i = 1; i < w.length; i++){
        d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

        if(d.clientHeight > height){
            height = d.clientHeight;
            console.log(w[i-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will log the last words of each line to the console except the last line. I leave that to you. The nice thing about this solution is that even after a window resize it works correctly.

By the way, [Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313758/yi-jiang) deserves all the credit for his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps) here on SO.