# Get last word js

Tags: javascript, jquery, words

This removes the last word. How do I get the last word (Stripe)?

```
var BaseShirtURL = "Base Shirt Draped with Fabric Stripe";
BaseShirtURL = BaseShirtURL.substring(0, BaseShirtURL.lastIndexOf(" "));
alert(BaseShirtURL);
```

Comment: `BaseShirtURL = BaseShirtURL.substring(BaseShirtURL.lastIndexOf(" "), BaseShirtURL.length);`

Comment: Here is a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/5673858/1011213

Comment: This is helpful. How is it too localized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the last word:

```
BaseShirtURL.split(' ').pop();
```

And to remove the last word you can do this:

```
BaseShirtURL = BaseShirtURL.replace(/\w+$/,'');
```

Comment: I've tested split vs slice method described in other answer, and for 5 million spins, split is faster. Graph(miliseconds): http://i.imgur.com/C6rvuCp.png test source: http://jsfiddle.net/4k3cf/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var BaseShirtURL = "Base Shirt Draped with Fabric Stripe";
var stripe = BaseShirtURL.substring(BaseShirtURL.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1,
    BaseShirtURL.length());
alert(stripe);
```