# How to remove the file path in javascript, leaving only the file name, regardless of filesystem

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a script that will remove everything after the last '\' from the file name, but I would like it to work in the circumstance that the user is uploading from a filesystem with forward slashes ('/') as well.

Here's the current code:

```
                var file1 = document.getElementById("file1");
                file1 = file1.value;
                var file_name1 = file1.split('\\').pop();
```

Essentially I just want the filename, rather than the directory.

Comment: I tried it and I was getting C:\fakepath\file.mp3

Answer (score 4):

You can adapt it like this using a regular expression to split :

```
var file_name1 = file1.split(/\/|\\/).pop();
```

Comment: Would that regular expression be the same as the one in `file1.split('\\|\/').pop();`?

Comment: @Jamil You need to use a regular expression literal so your code is wrong  but you're right in that the parenthesis aren't needed.

Comment: Why is the `'/'` delimiter necessary? The original expression `('\\')` worked to remove '\'. Also, I understand the single quote may mess it up? What's the difference between `('\\')` , `(\\)` , and `(/\\/)`?

Comment: @Jamil The `/` delimit a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). When you pass a string to split, it isn't converted to a regular expression, that's why you need to pass the regular expression.

Comment: Essentially, it denotes it's a regular expression and not a string?

Comment: Yes. But the syntax allows also to have less escapements in the literal than for a string. For example you don't need to escape the dot.

Comment: I see, so in conclusion, it's not necessary, but it signifies it's definitely a regular expression, thus allowing one to escape less.

Comment: It *is* necessary here : `split` doesn't do the same thing if passed a string or a regex. The other solution would have been to use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to build the regular expression object but it would have been slower and more verbose.

Comment: Alright. That makes sense. the delimiter differentiates it between a string and a regular expression. Without the delimiter, it thinks I'm just asking it to `split` it at `/\/|\\/`, literally, which unless the file had those characters specifically, wouldn't do anything.

Comment: That's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var file_name1 = file1.split(/[\\\/]/).pop();
```

This will split on the character class `[\\\/]` which means either `\` or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this easy stuff

```
var str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673752/searching-for-a-last-word-in-javascript.js';
    str = str.split(/[\\/]/).pop().split('.')[0];

console.log(str); // searching-for-a-last-word-in-javascript
```

> ## [JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTVr/4/)

> Or if you wan't the file extension aswell then just do this

```
var str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673752/searching-for-a-last-word-in-javascript.js';
    str = str.split(/[\\/]/).pop(); // searching-for-a-last-word-in-javascript.js
```

> ## [JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTVr/3/)

Comment: I was trying to avoid 3rd party scripts if I could.

Comment: @Jamil The links given by Connor are just for demonstration. His code doesn't need 3rd party scripts.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I scanned through it too quickly. The added "split('.')" is enlightening. I didn't think about that.  What I do not understand is why I need the '/' delimiter.

Comment: What do you think is a 3rd party script?

Comment: well that's how you split the filename into sections and then you take the last section which would be after the last `/`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What is the difference between (/[\\/]/) and ([\\/])?

Comment: You usually wrap a `REGEX` within `/.../` there isn't any difference